# Getting previous cell's image

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have two cells, and I want to get the previous elements image source. SO, that I can replace that images url.

```
string args =string.Format("'{0}'", tblCell.ID);
A.OnClientClick = String.Format("B({0}); return false;", args);
```

In the JS file :

```
function B( cid) {  
$("td[id$='" + cid + "']").css("background-color", colorSelected); // this works
}
```

But, I want to to get the previous 'td' image and replace that image, what should I do ?

I tried with this in the function B(but ti gave me undefined on alert) :

```
var a = $("td[id$='" + cid + "']").closest('td').prev();
alert(a.id);
```

Comment: Function `B` works for both cells I guess. So the alert is returning `undefined` if there is no previous `td` in the tree. For example when you click the first `td`. Just using `prev` should work on the second cell.

Comment: @Mouser It gives undefined

Answer (score 0):

If both cells are in the same row, you need to omit the .closest('td') call, because .closest() traverses tree upwards(http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Try this:

```
var a = $("td[id$='" + cid + "']").prev('td');
alert(a.id);
```

Comment: Not entirely true. Closest starts with the element itself.